# What is the difference between ActionCommand and DelegateCommand

Tags: c#, mvvm, icommand

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what are the differences and benefits in using  ActionCommand class from the Expression Blend and DelegateCommand class (Prism)?

If I understand correctly the DelegateCommand supports two delegates while the ActionCommand class supports only a single Execute delegate. Any other differences? After reading the documentation and online I still can't quite understand what are the benefits of using either one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx#id0190094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **DelegateCommand** allows delegating the commanding logic instead of requiring a handler in the code behind. It uses a delegate as the method of invoking a target handling method.
Like

```
public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        …
        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        …
    }
…
}
```